# Как отправить пользователю изображение через телеграм бота используя загрузку файла с помощью запроса HTTP?

Tags: c#

Пишу телеграм бота,который должен редактировать картинку пользователя и отправлять ему отредактированный вариант. Использую NuGet пакет Telegram.Bot.

Отправить изображение нужно этим способом - Uploading a file with the HTTP request

Но я не представляю как это реализовать . Можете привести пример или обьяснить как это сделать?

UPD
Еще как вариант можно загрузить фото по URL,что бы в итоге на него была ссылка такого вида https://github.com/TelegramBots/book/raw/master/src/docs/photo-ara.jpg .